# Handling document upload to iCloud/CloudKit not working on devices

Tags: swift, swiftui

My iOS/SwiftUI app offers the user to save documents to iCloud/CloudKit as a Data Type. Weirdly enough, it only works without any issues on the iOS-Simulator, while on real devices the pdfData entry in CloudKit is not getting saved properly.

iCloud capability is with iCloud Documents and CloudKit enabled and the container picked (otherwise it would probably not upload any data).

Documents Folder Usage is enabled.

I've tried to sort through the plist and possible entitlements which should be enabled, sadly I can't narrow down the issue.

```
Section(header: Text("Documents")) {
                    if let pdfURL = pdfURL {
                        Text(pdfURL.lastPathComponent)
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    }
                    Button("Pick document") {
                        isPresentingDocumentPicker = true
                    }
                    .fileImporter(
                        isPresented: $isPresentingDocumentPicker,
                        allowedContentTypes: [UTType.pdf],
                        allowsMultipleSelection: false
                    ) { result in
                        switch result {
                        case .success(let urls):
                            pdfURL = urls.first
                        case .failure(let error):
                            print("Error selecting file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                    }
                }
```

```
private func saveTest() {
        let newTest = Test(context: viewContext)
        newTest.id = UUID()
        if let pdfURL = pdfURL {
            newTest.pdfURL = pdfURL.absoluteString
            do {
                let pdfData = try Data(contentsOf: pdfURL)
                newTest.pdfData = pdfData
            } catch {
                print("Failed to load PDF data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
            dismiss()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: *is not getting saved properly* is a little vague. Does that mean it's not saved at all? Corrupted? A different file type? Something else? Does the code through any errors? Did you do some basic troubleshooting by adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected? If so, on what line was that and what was unexpected?